# C# how convert a string hex value in "bin" like xxd

Tags: c#, binary, hexdump

I'm try a solution for convert a string hex value in format "binary" (.bin),
like xxd command.

Example :
I have a string hexValue "17c7dfef853adcddb2c4b71dd8d0b3e3363636363"

On linux, i want a result like next :

echo "hexvalue" > file.hex
cat file.hex | xxd -r -p > file.bin

The hexdump of file.bin give :

> 0000000 17 c7 df ef 85 3a dc dd b2 c4 b7 1d d8 d0 b3 e3
>
> 0000010 36 36 36 36 36 36 36

My Program for convert this, is :

```
Private static string convertHex(string value)
{
    string[] hexVal = value.Split(' ');
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string hex in hexVal)
    {
         int val = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
         string stringValue = char.ConvertFromUtf32(val);
         s.Append(stringValue);
    }
    return s.ToString();
}

string MyString = "17 c7 df ef 85 3a dc dd b2 c4 b7 1d d8 d0 b3 e3 36 36 36 36 36";
string newString = converthex(MyString);
Console.WriteLine(newString);
File.WriteAllText("file2.bin", newString);
```

So now, when look the hexdump of file2.bin, i see :

> 0000000 17 c3 87 c3 97 c3 af c2 85 3a c3 9c c3 9d c2 b2
>
> 0000010 c3 84 c2 b7 1d c3 98 c3 90 c2 b3 a3 36 36 36

Why c3 or c2 exist in my new file ?
Have you a solution for me ?

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The `File.WriteAllText` is used for text file writing and it encodes passed string in UTF-8. This is why your additional bytes occured in the output file.

Your desired effect suggests you need a binary file without in-process converting to UTF-32 string. Here is example of working version:

```
class Program
{
    private static byte[] convertHex(string value)
    {
        string[] hexVal = value.Split(' ');
        byte[] output = new byte[hexVal.Length];
        var i = 0;
        foreach (string hex in hexVal)
        {
            byte val = (byte)(Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16));
            output[i++] = val;
        }
        return output;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string MyString = "17 c7 df ef 85 3a dc dd b2 c4 b7 1d d8 d0 b3 e3 36 36 36 36 36";
        var file = new FileStream("file2.bin", FileMode.Create);
        var byteArray = convertHex(MyString);
        file.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum, ok, it's my false.My program must calculate the md5sum in the hex string; in the binary format. But, i dont has seen, my function md5 it's call with utf8.getstring.

Okay, it's good, with your help. Thank you.
One day for this.. OMG !!